# Capturar en C++ el ingreso de posición (fila y columna)

Tags: c++, matriz

Debo resolver el siguiente ejercicio en lenguaje C++:
"*Esta operación recibe una matriz, la posición compuesta por fila y columna y un elemento, dicha operación debe sustituir en la matriz el elemento que se encuentra en la posición dada, por el elemento dado*."

La creación de la matriz, su recorrido e impresión en pantalla lo tengo.
También el solicitar el entero.
Lo que aún no funciona es: tomar la fila y columna (posición) ingresada por teclado y hacer que busque esa posición en la matriz, además de cambiar en esa posición por el entero ingresado.

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar el valor de un elemento dentro de una matríz necesitas dos cosas, primero el número de fila que deseas cambiar, segundo el número de columna.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

int Matriz[2][2] = { {1, 2},
                     {3, 4} };

//Estos spueden ser datos ingresados por el usuario
int fila_dada = 0;
int columna_dada = 1;

//Obtengo lo que hay en esa posiciC3n de la matrC-z
int resultado = Matriz[fila_dada][columna_dada];

std::cout << resultado << std::endl;



//Valor dado
int valor = 5;

//cambio lo que está en esa posición por valor
Matriz[fila_dada][columna_dada] = valor;

std::cout << Matriz[fila_dada][columna_dada] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.